# handling complex models with ngrx

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx, state-management

I'm interested in implementing the ngrx framework in my application, but I have some concerns about how much work that truly involves. Here are the models I am working with, as you can see the *Guild Model* is essentially just a collection of Players. I have plans to build onto Guilds but for now it's pretty bare. The *Player Model* is made up of some properties and an array of Skills, and each Skill has SkillRule.

```
{
    GuildName: "Guild",
    Players:[{
        PlayerName: "Player A",
        PlayerId: 1, 
        AttackType: "Melee",
        Skills:[{
            SkillName: "Heal Self", 
            SkillType: "Magic", 
            SkillRules:{
                RuleType:"HealRule",
                Cost: 100,
                FailChance:10
                Boost: false
            }
        }]
    }]
}

{
    PlayerName: "Player A",
    PlayerId: 1, 
    AttackType: "Melee",
    Skills:[{
        SkillName: "Heal Self", 
        SkillType: "Magic", 
        SkillRules:{
            RuleType:"HealRule",
            Cost: 100,
            FailChance:10
            Boost: false
        }
    }]
}
```

These values are all set through various UI elements such as text fields, dropdowns, radio buttons, etc.

What I am interested in doing is leveraging NGRX to manage the state of Guilds and the State of Players. The two are treated separately in the application, because Players can be considered "solo"; Guilds[] and Players[].

My question is (and hopefully it makes sense), how deep into these models does the state management need to be involved? For example, am I going to need actions/selectors/effects for the user to interact with all of the different properties? If the user wanted to update the players AttackType or the SkillRules, does that require an action/effect?

My thinking is use the stores to manage the two collections at the top level, and my components will take object/s from the store and present them to the users. I'd probably at the very least need an action to UPDATE_GUILD and UPDATE_PLAYER.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise you need Effects in NgRx to alter the Asynchronous part of the request where you want to process some data from server before you make final changes to the store.

Your question:

For example, am I going to need actions/selectors/effects for the user to interact with all of the different properties?

Answer is no not necessarily for all of them. You will definitely need the Actions to call the Reducers which will alter your applications Synchronous data for example if you made changes to the routes on a link being clicked this is a simple case which doesn't needs to have Effect and just the Reducer is fine.

But you will need the Action in both the cases Effects or the Reducer to dispatch a call and perform that operation.

Selector is needed to read back the value so if you need to read the values you will have to create the selector for it. If you don't need the value don't create one.

Effects are needed where you have an operation like for example getUserAccount information which is Asynchronous request and once this is processed in the effect then the effect will dispatch an action to a Reducer to commit the final response received from server to the state.

Solution is that you need to understand the exact requirement for making the state changes and identify if the request needs to be Synchronous or Asynchronous.

Comment: Hi there, for my application there is no concept of "state" in the backend. The state is only front end related. The front end will pass the current state to the backend, and the backend produces files based on what it's been passed.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything related to Backend in your question. Concept of state stays only for the Frontend you should clarify your question in short and precise manner with end statement for what you exactly need.